# thymeleaf th:field returns erros when i use the th:field

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

When i use the input like this i have no problems:

```
<input type="text" name="title" />
```

But if i put the th:name in the place i got an error 500:

```
<input type="text" th:field="${title}"/>
```

Começo a tomar erro 500, conforme abaixo

Here is the git repository: https://github.com/getJv/springStudy

Here is the error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Feb 07 23:03:56 BRST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/books/form.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/books/form.html]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [Thymeleaf Documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#inputs) here

**th:field** is used to populate the value automatically when pair with **th:object** with a context variable.

If you would like to render the tag's name dynamically, you should use **th:name** instead

---

### The example below will display "Winnie the Pooh" as the value

**BookController.java**

```
Book book = new Book();
book.setTitle("Winnie the Pooh");

ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("book/form");
mv.addObject("book", book);
```

**Thymeleaf:**

```
<form th:object="${book}">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{title}">
</form>
```

Comment: Oh @Chris it really works. but now i have a doubt... so ever i wish to use the th:object/field in m forms i will need to create a new  empty instance of my main  form class? something like these?

`@RequestMapping("/form")
 public ModelAndView form() {

  ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("books/form");
  Book book = new Book();
  mv.addObject("book", book);
  mv.addObject("priceTypes", PriceType.values());

  return mv;
 }
`

Comment: Than you. this Save my life. :D